# Rich Text Message Conversion - php

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode, richtext

Ok, I have been pulling my hair out with various encode/decode, and htmlentities(), and have yst to find a solution.  I am processing emails.  Some emails are like the following:

That change is detailed below:=0A=0AScott,=0A=0AWhat website ...

How do I convert the =0A=0A characters and other characters like that?

Comment: check [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458439/php-sent-emails-have-0a-0a-instead-of-new-lines)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo quoted_printable_decode($mailbody);
```